# Storing key value pairs in SQL / Stats Aggregator

Tags: sql, json, database

I'm writing a web application that needs to periodically collect data from an API and perform analysis on these stats to produce a dashboard for unique users. There are 236 unique 'stats' coming in from the API per user which are essentially key value pairs, where the value consists of either a string or number (or time duration or percent).

I'm trying to figure out how best to store this data. One option I thought of which would be the simplest approach was to store the raw JSON response against a userId and perform all analysis from that JSON. The obvious issue with this is that I need to be able to query the data easily and do things like ordering different users by one of the 236 unique stats. The other option would be in a relational database.

If I were to go the relational route, how is it best to store snapshots of data like this? I imagine creating a column for each of the 236 stats would be a bit of a mess, and annoying to add to in the future. I've looked at other relatively similar questions but haven't found anything right for me.

My thoughts so far:

- Create a StatsType(id, typename) containing 236 rows,
- and a UserStats(statid, userid, typeid, value, date_added) table, containing 236 rows **for each user update** from the API.

Would this end up being too huge as the app grows? (Think 200,000+ users) Thoughts would be much appreciated

Comment: its a many to many relationship, so a basic junction table setup should work. `UserTable`, `StatTypeTable`,`UserStatTable`. Other questions to consider would be are you going to be DW (data-warehousing - keeping historical data) as the data gets bigger you would want to consider partitioning and how your indexing is setup. Also you would want to consider your datatypes to be the smallest they can be.

Comment: @jkdba I guess size of the data is my main concern. I've not looked into Data-warehousing at all before, so this will be new to me. I'll definitely consider datatypes being small though

Answer (score 0):

Different value types is an argument for different columns. Your requirement to order users also prompts to have a single row for a user.
You may create kind of data dictionary to keep your code clean and udaptable minding future changes.

Comment: Hmm that's true about the types - but I've never seen 236 columns in a single row in practice? How could this be maintainable (especially if the code needs the ability to add new columns on the fly)?